# TabControl with bootsrap can not working (PHP)

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I have site builded on TabControl

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#edit" data-toggle="tab">Create/Edit</a></li>
   <li><a href="#questions" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Questions</a></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

with Bootsrap scripts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also I have server part with the same rules

```
 if(isset($_GET['active_tab']) AND $_GET['active_tab'] != ''){
switch ($_GET['active_tab']) {
        case 'edit':
                $layout->AddContentById('tab_edit_active', ' class="active"');
        $layout->AddContentById('pane_edit_active', ' active');
                break;  
        case 'questions':
                $layout->AddContentById('tab_questions_active', ' class="active"');
        $layout->AddContentById('pane_questions_active', ' active');
                break;
            ...
            default:
            $layout->AddContentById('tab_questions_active', ' class="active"');
        $layout->AddContentById('pane_questions_active', ' active');
         break;
 }

   }else{
$layout->AddContentById('tab_edit_active', ' class="active"');
$layout->AddContentById('pane_edit_active', ' active');
   }
```

Unfortunately when I click on any tab link nothing happen, variable active_tab missing on server, link looks as http://example.com#questions and of course server code don't working.
What going wrong? Code looks as Bootstrap must translated URL with suffix #questions to get parameter active_tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need replace href="#edit" with URL that will match your php code,
like this: href="CURRENTURL+"&active_tab=edit""